# code igniter server side validation for ajax form

Tags: php, codeigniter

There is the form validation library expects a form and needs form field names and a human name along with validation rules. I would love to use this library, but don't need a human name as I would just be validating and displaying a YES or NO. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the empty string?

Comment: I know that will work, but am just wondering if there is a better way to do this?